# How do I implement an onClick method in one child component that updates the text in a sibling component, based on the state in App.js?

Tags: reactjs

Every row in my `SideMenuContainer` corresponds to an object from schema.json, showing only the `name` property. The behavior I want is that when a row is clicked, the `PaneViewContainer` toggles to display the `name` and other properties of that respective object from the json.

In `App.js`, the data is passed to `SideMenuContainer` like so:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <MainContainer>
        <SideMenuContainer genInfoList={this.state.genInfoList}/>
        <PaneViewContainer genInfoList={this.state.genInfoList}/>
      </MainContainer>
    );
  }
```

In `SideMenuContainer`, every row is populated like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <SideMenuPane>
        <SideMenu>
          <div>
            <h2>GenInfo</h2>
            {this.props.genInfoList.map(genInfoElement => {
              return (
                <SideMenuRow>
                  {genInfoElement.name}
                </SideMenuRow>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </SideMenu>
      </SideMenuPane>
    );
  }
```

What I want to do is change the `genInfoList` information being displayed in the **PaneViewContainer** based on which row is clicked in its sibling, **SideMenuContainer**.

The entire `genInfoList` data is being passed to both sibling components from their parent `App.js`, so I want to change which portion of that data is loaded in the Pane based on the row clicked in the SideMenu.

I thought about using the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement it for this purpose. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have your information stored in the parent element of both components then you can just pass a function down as a prop and have all of your logic stored in the parent element.

```
changeInfoList = id => {
  //change your info list based on id or index or whatever
  this.setState({
    //your new list
  })
}

render() {
    return (
      <MainContainer>
        <SideMenuContainer changeInfoList={this.changeInfoList} genInfoList={this.state.genInfoList}/>
        <PaneViewContainer genInfoList={this.state.genInfoList}/>
      </MainContainer>
    );
  }
```

and then call changeInfoList from your component with props

```
render() {
    return (
      <SideMenuPane>
        <SideMenu>
          <div>
            <h2>GenInfo</h2>
            {this.props.genInfoList.map(genInfoElement => {
              return (
                <SideMenuRow>
                  {genInfoElement.name}
                  <button onClick={this.props.changeInfoList(genInfoElement.id)>CLick Me</button>
                </SideMenuRow>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </SideMenu>
      </SideMenuPane>
    );
  }
```

this is commonplace in react as you should have smart components and dumb components.  When you have components not in the same tree or spread far away then the context api is very useful.  In your case I don't think its necessary.

Comment: Ah makes sense! When I try this approach, I get an error that `_this.props.changeInfoList is not a function`. I imagine this is because the `this.props.changeInfoList` function is being passed in as a prop to PaneViewContainer, but being called in SideMenuContainer?

Comment: My bad i put the function on the wrong element.  The idea here is to store all of your data in the app.js file and then pass down all logic to the child components.  So store your list in the app.js and also your function in the app.js.  Then pass all data to the two child components including the function as a prop.  Here is an example on codesandbox for you to play with https://codesandbox.io/s/6y16qj86ln

Answer (score 0):

Without external state management, you would have to pass down a callback (as props), so the children can update the parent's state.

As the components get far away from each other, this pattern can get annoying (passing down callbacks each time). That's where external state management can help.

Here's a simple (and untested) example using a callback:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
        this.state = {count: 0};
    }

    increment() {
        let count = thist.state.count;
        this.setState({count: count + 1});
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <CounterButton increment={this.increment}/>
            <CounterDisplay count={this.state.count}/>
        </div>;
    }
}

class CounterButton extends React.Component {

    render() {
        let increment = this.props.increment;
        return <button onClick={increment}>Plus One</button>;
    }
}

class CounterDisplay extends React.Component {

    render() {
        let count = this.props.count;
        return <span>{count}</span>;
    }
}
```